# Gcloud internal Loadbalancer unable to connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created 1 Instance Group having two instances of Redis running on port 6379.

Created 1 internal load balancer (TCP)  having backend of Redis instance group.

Issue 1 - If i add Healthcheck of TCP 6379 LB status shows no healthy instance, when I change to tcp 80 LB shows healthy.

Issue 2 - Unable to connect to LB IP from another instance of same project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following checks to be performed in order to isolate both the issues.

1. Make sure the redis service is running on the specific port and is not bind to a specific address (e.g., localhost) and is listening for all addresses (0.0.0.0/0) on port 6379.
2. Make sure proper firewall rules are set to allow health check probes (130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16) to the reach the redis backends on port 6379.
3. Make sure the client instance originating traffic, i.e., the instance trying to connect to Internal Load Balancer (ILB), belongs to the same VPC network (but can be in a different subnet) and region as the internal load balancing forwarding rule IP, backend services, and instance groups.

Further details on internal load balancing can be found in this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal).